# how to get (access token) for youtube data api? Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [**YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN**] **issue is here how to resolve this, i am confused.**
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#Obtaining_Access_Tokens

Comment: thank you..!!!  MariuszS i got it and its working fine.

Comment: @MariuszS one more thing is can you tell me is there any **post or get request** from where i can get token or is there only a web page [link](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&response_type=token) **method**.

Comment: only this "website link" can be used to get token

Comment: @MariuszS than how can i use it in android app? because android webView giving error to run this due to security issues...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an explanatory answer to this problem that I was also facing, it may help you and others!!

Basically, you have two strings:

- the ClientId (it's used on both: client and server)
- the SecretKey (that must never come to the client-side!)

The user sees in the page a link: Click here to login (e.g.). When he clicks there he is redirected to the Google pages. He is asked to accept your application. If he clicks the Deny button you will get an error message: Access denied by the user (probably..). If he clicks Yes, you will get a temp code that is used to get the access token. You will make a POST request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token providing the `client_id, secret_key, code, redirect_uri, and grant_type` parameters in the form data.

Then you will finally get the access token!

Complete discussion link:
https://github.com/IonicaBizau/youtube-api/issues/5